# How to create a function for my conversions

Tags: python, zelle-graphics

These are the instructions for my project.

> Define different functions for the conversions. Call these functions.

I have created my window with the entry box and text boxes. I have a function but I know I should use `setText()` to display the calculations in my text boxes. And I think I need to use an statement for the "invalid input" part.

```
entry1= Entry(Point(win.getWidth()/2,100),25)
entry1.setFill("White")
entry1.draw(win)

gramstext= Text(Point(160,136), "Grams")
gramstext.setTextColor("black")
gramstext.draw(win)

gramsbox= Rectangle(Point(107,147),Point(294,175))
gramsbox.setFill("white")
gramsbox.draw(win)

kilotext= Text(Point(160,195), "Kilograms")
kilotext.setTextColor("black")
kilotext.draw(win)

kilobox= Rectangle(Point(107,207),Point(294,235))
kilobox.setFill("white")
kilobox.draw(win)


ouncetext= Text(Point(160, 250), "Ounces")
ouncetext.setTextColor("black")
ouncetext.draw(win)

ouncebox= Rectangle(Point(107, 262),Point(294,290))
ouncebox.setFill("white")
ouncebox.draw(win)

#From here on is the updated code

button1= Rectangle(Point(142,290),Point(206,310))
button1.setOutline("black")
button1.setFill("white")
button1.draw(win)

button= Text(Point(win.getWidth()/3.5,300),"Convert")
button.setOutline("black")
button.draw(win)

closebutton1= Rectangle(Point(362, 290),Point(438,310))
closebutton1.setOutline("black")
closebutton1.setFill("white")
closebutton1.draw(win)

closebutton = Text(Point(win.getWidth() / 1.5, 300), "Close")
closebutton.setOutline("black")
closebutton.draw(win)
```

Iwant my conversions for grams, kg and ounces to display in the text boxes that I created, but I can't seem to figure it out.

*EDIT I am now able to display my conversions in the window. My issue is getting my close button to work. If I put it before While True , User has to double click to convert. I have updated the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want my conversions for grams, kg and ounces to display in the text
>   boxes that I created

The problem is, along with never actually calling `poundsTo()`, you didn't create *text boxes*, you created *rectangles* which don't respond to a `setText()` method.  I've reworked and cleaned up your code below to get it to basically function:

```
from graphics import *

def poundsTo():
    grams = number * 452.592
    kgrams = number / 0.453592
    ounces = number * 16

    gramsbox.setText(grams)
    kilobox.setText(kgrams)
    ouncebox.setText(ounces)

win = GraphWin("Conversions", 600, 400)

poundstext = Text(Point(160, 50), "Pounds:")
poundstext.draw(win)

poundsbox = Entry(Point(win.getWidth() / 2, 50), 25)
poundsbox.setFill("White")
poundsbox.draw(win)

gramstext = Text(Point(160, 100), "Grams:")
gramstext.draw(win)

gramsbox = Text(Point(win.getWidth() / 2, 100), "")
gramsbox.draw(win)

kilotext = Text(Point(160, 150), "Kilograms:")
kilotext.draw(win)

kilobox = Text(Point(win.getWidth() / 2, 150), "")
kilobox.draw(win)

ouncetext = Text(Point(160, 200), "Ounces:")
ouncetext.draw(win)

ouncebox = Text(Point(win.getWidth() / 2, 200), "")
ouncebox.draw(win)

button = Text(Point(win.getWidth() / 2, 300), "Convert")
button.draw(win)

while True:
    win.getMouse()

    number = int(poundsbox.getText())
    poundsTo()
```

Now you need to follow the assignment requirements about: dealing with the user entering something that's not a number; defining different functions for the conversions, not one common one.  An "Exit" button would be a nice addition.  Also, making the GUI more pleasant wouldn't hurt either...

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I have updated my code and changed the overall appearance. Now I have an issue with the close button. For some reason, I can't get it to work properly without having the user click twice to convert.

Comment: @pangie, since you didn't provide complete code, I can only guess.  My belief is that the code that checks if the close button was pressed should be *inside* the `while` loop, not before it.  That is, you should be able to do multple `Convert` runs and then hit `Close` -- all part of that same loop.  If this continues to be a problem, start a new OP question for this issue with complete code.